# Rails routing / clipping mistyped urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

in my router I have:

```
get 'cars/:make', to: 'cars#make'
```

This works fine when people visit /cars/dodge or /cars/toyota, but when people enter /cars/make-does-not-exist, I would prefer the page drop 'make-does-not-exist' from the url, and send them to /cars.

In my cars#make controller I have some logic that properly sets my view:

```
def make
 case params[:make]
   when "dodge"
    @text = "dodge text"
   when "toyota"
    @text = "toyota text"
   else
    @text = "default text"
    #how do I send people to /cars, and not /cars/make-does-not-exist
 end
 render :index  #render index with the @text that we just set
end
```

How can I set the url from the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the `'/cars'` route exists, you should use a redirection: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to redirect people to `/cars`, you would have to add to your routes

```
get 'cars', to: 'cars#make'
```

And modify your controller to look more like

```
def make
 case params[:make]
   when nil
    @text = "default text"
   when "dodge"
    @text = "dodge text"
   when "toyota"
    @text = "toyota text"
   else
    wrong_make = true
 end
 if defined? wrong_make
   redirect_to 'cars'
 else
   render :index
 end
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks this works.  One note: I had to use `redirect_to '/cars'`  (added a slash).